# Can the return type of a static generic method depend on its arguments?

Tags: java, generics

I "simply" want to write a static generic method that takes the generic `Collection<E>` of any type `E` as its input, and outputs a result of the appropriate type `Vector<E>`. Since the type `E` is always known at compile-time, this should not be a problem - but it is... Thus, a call should later look like:

```
Collection<String> coll = ...
Vector<String> vec = Convert.toVector(coll); // either this or...
Vector<String> vec = Convert<String>.toVector(coll);
```

Here is what I tried - all without success:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Convert<E> {

    // 1st try, same type E as class => Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E
    public static Vector<E> toVector1(Collection<E> coll) {
        return new Vector<E>();
    }

    // 2nd try, a new type X. => Error: X cannot be resolved to a type
    public static Vector<X> toVector2(Collection<X> coll) {
        return new Vector<X>();
    }

    // 3rd try, using wildcard. => Error: Cannot instantiate the type Vector<?> 
    public static Vector<?> toVector3(Collection<?> coll) {
        return new Vector<?>();
    }

    // 4th try, using bounded wildcard. => Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E
    public static Vector<? extends E> toVector4(Collection<? extends E> coll) {
        return new Vector<E>();
    }
}
```

Is this not possible at all? And if not, is there a good reason why not? Or am I just doing it wrong? Probably there is some solution using Lambda expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the JDK documentation: "For static generic methods, the type parameter section must appear before the method's return type.". So it should look like

```
public static <E> Vector<E> toVector1(Collection<E> coll) {
    return new Vector<E>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the official documentation, I should really RTFM, e.g., https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html.

Answer (score 5):

You should give your static method its own generic type parameter :

```
public static <T> Vector<T> toVector1(Collection<T> coll) {
    return new Vector<T>();
}
```

You were missing the generic type parameter declaration (`<T>`) before the return type of the method.

Answer (score 2):

```
// 1st try, same type E as class => Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E
public static Vector<E> toVector1(Collection<E> coll) {
    return new Vector<E>();
}
```

This is because you've already defined a type-parameter, called `E`, on instance context and the compiler doesn't allow you to use it on static context.

---

```
// 2nd try, a new type X. => Error: X cannot be resolved to a type
public static Vector<X> toVector2(Collection<X> coll) {
    return new Vector<X>();
}
```

Here, even though you don't use the instance type-parameter `E`, but another one, called `X`, the former is not correctly defined. When introducing method-scoped type-parameters, you have to do:

```
public static <X> Vector<X> toVector2(Collection<X> coll) {
    return new Vector<X>();
}
```

---

```
// 3rd try, using wildcard. => Error: Cannot instantiate the type Vector<?> 
public static Vector<?> toVector3(Collection<?> coll) {
    return new Vector<?>();
}
```

The error is simply because the wildcard `<?>` can be only used in return-types and on initialization, but not on instantiation (like you've done).

---

```
// 4th try, using bounded wildcard. => Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E
public static Vector<? extends E> toVector4(Collection<? extends E> coll) {
    return new Vector<E>();
}
```

The reason is the same as 1st try. You can fix this by having:

```
public static <X> Vector<? extends X> toVector4(Collection<? extends X> coll) {
    return new Vector<X>();
}
```

However, note that when you use this method, you won't be able **to add** anything but `null` to the resulting list.